# force popup to display on the top of the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, visualforce

I have a popup that gets fired when I hover over a link in an iframe embedded inside the main page.

Currently that popup is rendering on the iframe and gets clipped. I want the popup to display on the top and not in the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, this can't be done in a reliable and simple way.

You would have to display the popup in the parent frame, because that's the only one that can hover above your iframe. If the popup is bound to the mouse position, the amount of effort required to cross-calculate the correct positions and transfer them to the parent frame is *huge* and awfully complicated.